# Contingency Tables and ANOVA are they same?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, multiple-comparisons, contingency-tables

It seems contingency table and 2 way ANOVA are the same. Is it True? If not what is the difference and when do we use each one of them

Comment: In what respect to you think they are the same?

Comment: @mdewey Consider 2-way ANOVA, My Null hypothesis will be that the mean of the factors are not same, and Alternate otherwise, Which is what we measure in contingency table that weather any of the rows and columns are correlated. Except for the fact that contingency table is for distribution and ANOVA is for values all other parts are same. Just they are different tests for same type of problem

Answer (score 2):

In a contingency table you have a variable X in rows, another variable Y in columns and the table itself  is the frequency of joint occurrence of the ith value of X with the jth value of Y. There are TWO variables. In a two-way ANOVA test with a single observation (K=1) you have a factor X in rows, another factor Y in columns and the table itself shows the values of a THIRD variable which is subject to the ith value of factor X and the jth value of factor Y. There are THREE variables. When you make use of contingency tables you want to see whether variables X and Y are related. When you make use of a two-way ANOVA test you want to see the influence of two variables X and Y on a third variable, say Z.